What symmetry protects the mid-gap state and enable the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ index of the Fu-Kane pump?
I am trying to make sense of this celebrated paper by Fu and Kane.
We have a family of 1D bulk Hamiltonians $\lbrace H(\tau)\rbrace$ dependent on the $2\pi$-periodic adiabatic parameter $\tau$.  And there is the usual time reversal operation $T = \mathcal{K} \, i\sigma_y$.  The only symmetry assumption emphasized by Fu and Kane is the following:
$$T H(-\tau) T^{\dagger} = H(\tau)$$
That is, if $\tau = 0 \, \text{or}\,\pm\pi$, $H(\tau)$ is time-reversal invariant.  Otherwise, $T$ maps $H(\tau)$ and $H(-\tau)$ to each other.
From here, they go on to calculate some $\mathbb{Z}_2$ index of the bulk $H(\tau)$ at $\tau = 0$ and $\tau = \pi$, and argue that something gets twisted in between if $H(0)$ and $H(\pi)$ has different $\mathbb{Z}_2$ sign.  They emphasize that the index is only defined for $T$-invariant Hamiltonians.  My interpretation is that the adiabatic path connecting $\tau = 0$ and $\pi$ brings $H(\tau)$ out of the symmetry class, thus allowing the twist without closing the gap.  All sounds very reasonable except one problem:  spinful time reversal in 1D (class AII) does not support a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ topological index.
If you look at their tight binding toy model, $H(0)$ and $H(\pi)$ has a whole bunch of extra symmetries (you even get to choose whether you want DIII or CII!).  It appears to me that rather than time reversal, the chiral symmetry is responsible for the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and the protection of mid-gap state when there is an edge.
So, my questions:

Must $H(0)$ and $H(\pi)$ additionally have a chiral symmetry?
If not (I think Fu and Kane imply that time reversal is enough), how do I reconcile this with the ten-fold way?

